# Show that a group of order 440 has a unique subgroup of order 55

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I need some help with this, because I have been struggling on it although it seems really easy.

I wanna show that a group of order $440$ has a unique subgroup of order $55$. It is very easy to see the existence of this subgroup (using the Second isomorphism theorem), but I can't find the way too show that it's unique.

Any help will be appreciated,

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying Sylow's theorem to the 11-Sylows in $G$ of order 440, we see that $G$ has a unique 11-Sylow, which is thus normal--call it $H$.  Now, the subgroups of order 55 in $G$ correspond 1-1 to the subgroups of order 5 in $G/H$ which are their images.  (If this isn't obvious at first, note that since $H$ is the only order 11 subgroup of $G$, it must be a subgroup of every order 55 subgroup of $G$, by Sylow applied to the order 55 subgroup.)  But $G/H$ has order 40 and clearly (by Sylow) has only 1 subgroup of order 5.  Thus, $G$ has only one subgroup of order 55.

Comment: But there can be either 1 or 11 5-Sylow's, isn't that right?

Comment: Yes, you can have 11 5-Sylows in $G$, but they would all be subgroups of the unique subgroup of order 55.

Comment: Okay thanks. About this:  "G/H has order 40 and clearly (by Sylow) has only 1 subgroup of order 5.". Is this true because all 5-Sylows must be disjoint?

Comment: Right, because none of 2, 4, or 8 are congruent to 1 mod 5